# Viber icon is not available in Font Awsome 4

Tags: font-awesome

I am using Font Awsome Version 4.7.0.

Currently, I need to get Viber Icon but it is not available in the above-mentioned version.

I am not able to upgrade the Font Awsome version since it can affect to the whole system.

Is there a way to include Viber icon to the existing version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

I could find the below-mentioned repository which includes all the necessary CSS and font files generate the Viber icon.

I just needed to import additional Font files and CSS files related only to Viber Icon and import the CSS file.

Repository : http://kukac7.github.io/fa-viber